# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns

Tags: java, sql, derby

I'm calling a java function using a url from my front end to insert data to the data base

This is my url:

```
http://localhost:49779/BackEnd/mobile/rideshare/addride/1590105&toyota&4&Himalaya&10&good&12-04-2017
```

This is the Java method:

```
@Path("addride/{student_id}&{vehicle}&{seats}&{destination}&{price}&{description}&{datetime}")
@GET

public void addRide(@PathParam ("student_id") int S_id, @PathParam ("vehicle") String vehicle, @PathParam("seats") int seats, 
        @PathParam("destination") String destination, @PathParam("price") int price, @PathParam("description") String description,@PathParam("datetime") String datetime) throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
    Connection myCon = null;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
     myCon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ride_share","yadhu","yadhu");
    Statement st=myCon.createStatement();

    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO RIDES (STUDENT_ID,VEHICLE,SEATS,DESTINATION,PRICE,DESCRIPTION,DATETIME) VALUES "
            + "("+S_id+",'"+vehicle+"',"+seats+",'"+destination+"',"+price+",'"+description+"','"+datetime+"')");

}
```

The table RIDES has a column RIDES_ID, which is made with auto increment property.

This is how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE RIDES (RIDE_ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (start with 1000), STUDENT_ID INTEGER, VEHICLE VARCHAR(200), SEATS INTEGER, DESTINATION VARCHAR(200), PRICE INTEGER, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200), DATETIME VARCHAR(50));
```

The insertion works when I do it implicitly, but when I call the method using the url it's showing the error. I couldn't find the mistake please help me.

Comment: Is it Oracle or Derby? You seem to be using an Oracle drive but the URL references a Derby database?Also , what do you mean by 'do it implicitly'?

Comment: You need to user proper parameters instead of concatenating values into your query. [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @dsp_user 'do it implicitly' : inside the netbeans

Comment: @sqlZim I will have a look at it, thanks

Comment: But all my other functions working this way except this one

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the number of columns you are trying to add does not match the number of declared columns.
IE.  insert into table (col1, col2) values (val1, val2, val3).

This could be due to a code error when reading the parameters from the URL. 
This can also be due if one of the values your are passing contains a coma "," .

first level of debug:
Do SYSTEM.OUT.PRINTLN to the statement before executing it and check its outcome in the console to spot possible errors.

Also, please do use PreparedStatement instead of Statement since this will prevent your code from having SQL Injections and avoid many errors.

Comment: the number of columns seems same in both query and in the db as per I have shown.

Comment: If one value of ur params contain a coma it will be considered as 2. Have u tried my preivous suggestions first?